# Using :before pseudo-element on '<a href' that is wrapping a <button> element - can it be done?

Tags: html, css, button, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I am interested in seeing if I can use the `:before` pseudo-element on a `<a href` wrapped around a `<button>` element?

Currently, Firefox shows a thin blue line behind the `<button>` element - this is due to it being wrapped in an `<a href`.

If I use an **inline style** within the `<a href` the line goes away:

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><button>
```

However, since I have `<button>` elements on multiple pages, I want to target them using **CSS** if possible (and I don't particularly want to go and add a class to all the `<a href` that are wrapping the `<button>`'s on the site). This is where I was thinking the `:before` pseudo-element would come in handy but it doesn't seem to work:

```
a:before button{
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

This is how the `<button>`'s display in Firefox, see the blue default text-decoration applied to the `<a href`. The reason it is showing up only on the right hand side is because a class of `margin-left:5px` is applied to the `<button>` element:

[image]

Here's a basic version of the buttons up on jsfiddle (ignore slight appearance differences): http://jsfiddle.net/Vtjue/2/

Any ideas?

Comment: "Firefox shows a thin blue line behind the <button> element - this is due to it being wrapped in an `<a href`" - could you expand on this part?

Comment: Sorry thirtydot, it's applying the default blue underline to the <a href which is displaying behind the <button> element. The button element's style hides most of the default text-decoration, but shows up on the left hand side where a margin-left:5px has been applied.

Comment: What's a `<button>` doing in an `<a>` in the first place?

Comment: I see. Could you show some more of the relevant HTML/CSS? It *could* be possible to get rid of that "default blue underline" without resorting to `:before`.

Comment: @thirtydot, there's not really that much css/html to it. The button element has it's own styling (font-weight, color etc.) and the HTML is as basic as <button>View Dividends</button> but with a <a href wrapped around it.

Comment: Well, unless I'm missing something obvious, can't you just do something like `#containingElement a { text-decoration: none }`?

Comment: Yes, I could, but then that would remove all the text:decoration:underline from the text-links throughout the site.

Comment: So you can probably use some fancy CSS3 selectors (we're talking about Firefox, so they'll work) such as `not()`. This is why I want to see more of your HTML/CSS. It *might* be possible to hack something that will do what you want.

Comment: I was thinking the not() selector would be a good option (or at least a possible) option. Any chance of a possible snippet (html/css) of how it might look without supplying the huge amount css and html from the site?

Comment: I'd suggest linking to the site would be an easier option than pasting the code. I'm not intimately familiar with the CSS3 selectors, and I don't know anything about your site. These reasons combined means I'm too foggy here so I can't give you any useful actual code.

Comment: No worries, I've thrown it up on jsfiddle. Check out the buttons here: http://jsfiddle.net/Vtjue/2/

Comment: That doesn't really help me help you with what I'm thinking of trying. It would be a case of doing something like `#mostSpecificContainingElementWeCanFind a { text-decoration: none }` and then adding the underline back onto the *other* links (the links which don't contain a button - *maybe* there will be a way to differentiate them) within the chosen element. Sorry to sound like a parrot, but "I need to see more of your HTML". I might just be wasting both our time here, but I simply don't know if that's the case yet :(

Comment: Arrrrrr, gottcha. I see where your going here with the not() selector. So if there is a specific (consistent) container in which the buttons sit within, apply the not() selector to apply text-decoration:underline to everything but that container. I'll be able to take a look into this shortly, I don't want to take up any more of your time, but will let you know how I go. Thanks heaps for your insight.

Comment: @Dan: Something like that - at least I seem to have given you an idea. Hope you can get it working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:before` and `:after` selectors refer to generated elements that exist separately from the DOM and are rendered by the browser on the fly. That means you don't use them to traverse your HTML structure.

Due to the nature of CSS selectors, you cannot select an `a` that contains a `button`, only the other way around (`button` contained by `a`). I'm afraid your only options are to use a class, or move your `button`s away from your `a` because they semantically don't belong there.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback BoltClock. I think you might be right, just going to see if anyone else comes up with a CSS solution.